# How to determine given coordinates are overlaps on polyline route google maps iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I need to find a path between 2 locations. I have a polyline on google map and after give another 2 location points(draw a polyline), is it possible to know the new polyline is overlaps the previous polyline. Or is there a way to determine those new coordinates are on previous polyline. I've googled many times and there is no solution found. Thanks in advance.

[image]